# How to swap the values in a two column subset in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, tidyr, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe, df, in R that contains a column for sex and a column for age. During the data cleaning process, I noticed that for a few values the age and sex were flipped, so that the data looks like this:

```
    SequenceNo    Sex       Age
 1. sequence1     Male      65
 2. sequence2     Female    45
 3. sequence3     21        Male
 4. sequence4     Female    12
```

I know I can go row by row and manually assign the correct values to fix the data, but is there an easy, unifying solution that can flip only the rows where the data is mismatched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could create a logical index (either use `grepl` to check only digits (`\\d+` - for numeric floats, use `[0-9.]+` and assuming there are negative values `-?`) from start (`^`) to end (`$`) of string or reverse `\\D` any non-digit or may use `as.numeric/as.integer` and check with `NA` elements using `is.na`) and swap it by swapping the column names, then change the type of the columns with `type.convert`

```
i1 <- grepl("^-?[0-9.]+$", df$Sex)
df[i1, c("Sex", "Age")] <- df[i1, c("Age", "Sex")]
df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
```

-output

```
> df
   SequenceNo    Sex Age
1.  sequence1   Male  65
2.  sequence2 Female  45
3.  sequence3   Male  21
4.  sequence4 Female  12
> str(df)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ SequenceNo: chr  "sequence1" "sequence2" "sequence3" "sequence4"
 $ Sex       : chr  "Male" "Female" "Male" "Female"
 $ Age       : int  65 45 21 12
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(SequenceNo = c("sequence1", "sequence2", "sequence3", 
"sequence4"), Sex = c("Male", "Female", "21", "Female"), Age = c("65", 
"45", "Male", "12")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1.", 
"2.", "3.", "4."))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked great with the example and did not work on my full dataset... i1 only returned false values, unlike the example df here where when I ran it I got the 3 FALSE and 1 TRUE. Looking at my code I may have made an mistake in the example, since all my numbers for age are in the format 10.0, 12.0, etc. Any suggestions? Would this matter for the grepl logical index?

Comment: @bergdoktor just change the `\\d+` to `[0-9.]+` as in the updated the `\\d+` doesn't include dots.  Also, do you have negative values `-`?

Comment: THANK YOU, this worked!! No negative values, just a handful of NAs. Thanks again so much

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** to avoid `NA` (thanks to rjen):
We create a `helper` column than do the same as in answer 1:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    mutate(helper = paste0(Sex, Age),
           Age = parse_number(helper),
           Sex = str_replace_all(helper, "[:digit:]", "")) %>% 
    select(-helper)
```

```
SequenceNo    Sex Age
1.  sequence1   Male  65
2.  sequence2 Female  45
3.  sequence3   Male  21
4.  sequence4 Female  12
```

First answer:
With `paste0(Sex, Age)` we combine both columns:

1. We replace all digits with nothing i.e. remove all digits
2. We extract the numbers only

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    mutate(Sex = str_replace_all(paste0(Sex, Age), "[:digit:]", "")) %>% 
    mutate(Age = parse_number(paste0(Sex, Age)))
```

```
  SequenceNo    Sex Age
1  sequence1   Male  65
2  sequence2 Female  45
3  sequence3   Male  NA
4  sequence4 Female  12
```

Comment: To avoid getting the NA, the original ```Sex``` needs to be maintained until the new ```Age``` has been produced. There is a similar requirement for my solution.

Comment: uups overlooked. thanks you. will correct.

Answer (score 2):

An approach using `if_else()`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(SexNew = if_else(Sex %in% c('Male', 'Female'), Sex, Age),
         Age = if_else(Age %in% 1:120, Age, Sex)) %>%
  select(-Sex, Sex = SexNew)

#   SequenceNo Age    Sex
# 1  sequence1  65   Male
# 2  sequence2  45 Female
# 3  sequence3  21   Male
# 4  sequence4  12 Female
```